# How do you use bundles in your code when you browserify an npm module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browserify, fuse

I want to use a javascript library called fuse.js. (https://fusejs.io/)  in my vanilla javascript app.

I npm install fuse and then add

```
const Fuse = require('fuse.js')

...other javascript functions here
```

to the top of my script.js file. (i have trie removing the .js but the lib is called fuse.js in the node_modules folder)

I then run:

```
browserify script.js -o bundle.js
```

then I add the bundle.js to my index.html

```
  <script type="module" src="bundle.js"></script>
```

then, no matter what I do I can't access the Fuse object or any of my other javascript functions...It does load the bundle...but it's completely "closed", I can't use any functions in it.

I have seen that the guys export the bundle to the window object, but there are a lot of people saying this isn't best practice?

Are there any good resources anyone can recommend that I can study up to understand the concept of

> I see a useful library on npm, and I use it in my front-end code

(fuse.js does have a cdn that I can just include in the script tag, but I want to know for future use how to use npm modules in my front-end workflow?)